# T-SQL: Joining a table of chronological data to itself

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've a SQL table of start times and finish times for several different cycles running through a system. The table below is a simplified sample of the data I'm dealing with.

```
Batch# Event# Event  Timestamp
1      1      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000
1      2      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000
1      3      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000
1      4      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      5      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      6      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
2      1      Start  2015-07-01 12:35:32.000
2      2      End    2015-07-01 12:36:32.000
```

I want to produce a table which looks something like this.

```
Batch# Event# Event Timestamp                 Event# Event Timestamp
1      1      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  4      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      2      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  5      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      3      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  6      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
2      1      Start  2015-07-01 12:35:32.000  2      End    2015-07-01 12:36:32.000
```

I've tried using a left outer join but I'm getting extra rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 as T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 as T2
ON T1.Batch_no = T2.Batch_no
WHERE T1.Event = 'Start'
      AND T2.Event = 'End'


Batch# Event# Event Timestamp                 Event# Event Timestamp
1      1      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  1      4      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      1      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  1      5      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      1      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  1      6      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      2      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  1      4      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      2      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  1      5      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      2      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  1      6      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      3      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  1      4      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      3      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  1      5      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
1      3      Start  2015-07-01 12:31:31.000  1      6      End    2015-07-01 12:33:32.000
2      1      Start  2015-07-01 12:35:32.000  2      2      End    2015-07-01 12:36:32.000
```

Comment: Can you tell or explain how should we connect start and end? As I see you don't use Event# columns

Comment: Are Batch# and Event# unique?

Comment: I think your data is oversimplified.  You've left out any way of telling which end corresponds to which start.

Comment: The first start should be connected to the first end. The second start to the second end, etc.

Batch# and Event# are not unique individually but the combination of both is unique.

I possibly have oversimplified because the database is quite complicated and I've only been using SQL and databases for a week, so I apologise if that is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this:

You can use row_number() to number the rows in each partition, once for start and once for end and then do a join.

```
with 
cte_start as (
  select 
    *, 
    r_start = row_number() over (partition by [batch#] order by [event#]) 
  from t where [event] = 'Start'),
cte_end   as (
    select 
      *, 
      r_end = row_number() over (partition by [batch#] order by [event#]) 
    from t where [event] = 'End')

select 
    s.[Batch#], s.[Event#], s.[Event], s.[Timestamp], 
                e.[Event#], e.[Event], e.[Timestamp] 
from cte_start s
join cte_end   e on s.Batch# = e.Batch# and s.r_start = e.r_end
```

[Sample SQl Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eab0c/1)

Sample result:

```
| Batch# | Event# | Event |              Timestamp | Event# | Event |              Timestamp |
|--------|--------|-------|------------------------|--------|-------|------------------------|
|      1 |      1 | Start | July, 01 2015 12:31:31 |      4 | End   | July, 01 2015 12:33:32 |
|      1 |      2 | Start | July, 01 2015 12:31:31 |      5 | End   | July, 01 2015 12:33:32 |
|      1 |      3 | Start | July, 01 2015 12:31:31 |      6 | End   | July, 01 2015 12:33:32 |
|      2 |      1 | Start | July, 01 2015 12:35:32 |      2 | End   | July, 01 2015 12:36:32 |
```

Comment: As best I can tell this works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine. Let me know if it needs any tweaks.

### SQL Server 2008 and above

```
WITH CTE_YourTable --My version of your table
AS
(
    SELECT  row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Batch#,[Event] ORDER BY Event#), --This numbers the events for each batch and type.
        *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (1, 1, 'Start', '2015-07-01 12:31:31.000'),
                (1, 2, 'Start', '2015-07-01 12:31:31.000'),
                (1, 3, 'Start', '2015-07-01 12:31:31.000'),
                (1, 4, 'End', '2015-07-01 12:33:32.000'),
                (1, 5, 'End', '2015-07-01 12:33:32.000'),
                (1, 6, 'End', '2015-07-01 12:33:32.000'),
                (2, 1, 'Start', '2015-07-01 12:35:32.000'),
                (2, 2, 'End', '2015-07-01 12:36:32.000')
    ) AS A(Batch#,Event#,[Event],[Timestamp])
)

SELECT  A.Batch#,
        A.Event#,
        A.[Event],
        A.[Timestamp],
        B.Event#,
        B.[Event],
        B.[Timestamp]
FROM CTE_YourTable      AS A
LEFT JOIN CTE_YourTable AS B
    ON      A.Batch#    = B.Batch# --Only join matching batches
        AND A.row_num   = B.row_num --Match the rows so the first start goes with the first end, second start to second end etc...
        AND B.[Event]   = 'End' --Only end events on the right table aliased "B"
WHERE A.[Event] = 'Start' --Only start events on the left table aliased "A"
ORDER BY A.Batch#,A.Event#
```